# Google App Script limits on number of times doGet can be called

Tags: google-apps-script

The google script limitations link shows that we can do `URL Fetch calls    20,000 / day`. Now thats looks quiet ambiguous to me. Inside script, you can use the UrlFetchApp to make get/post requests to external urls. But what if we are calling a **deployed** google script from external non script client(e.g. web browser/mobile device ). 
Does that imply that we can only call the script(with url say abc/exec)20000 times a day(20000=total sum of times the script is called from all client devices) from outside of google app script?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the relationship between fetching an URL from within a script and running an app from a browser. I never saw any mention of a limit about how many times a webapp could be called but there are probably limits on the total processing time a script can use. The quota dashboard specifies the maximum processing time used by triggers, it does not however specify a limit on processing time by a human user.

If Google does not specify it that means they don't care or that they don't want us to know... in both case the result is the same:  we have no way to get the info.

That said, I never encounter any issue with an app being called too often even if I know that some of them are heavily used sometimes.

Was your question purely rhetorical or did you experience some real situation?

Comment: Thank you for your question.Upvoted already! Actually I am trying to use google script for implementing simple web service for my android application. The app would be used by tens of thousands of users. So before I distribute the app to thousands of users and realize that I have exceeded the quota, I wished to be on the safer side.